# Firefox select dropdown keeps refreshing/reverting to default option due to running Javascript - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, html-select, selection

I'm building an app in AngularJS and am having trouble with select dropdown menus when using Firefox.

When I click a select menu and hover over the options, it resets the selected option, from the one my cursor is hovering over, to the default/first option.  When the number of options is large, it becomes very difficult to select the correct option.

The app requires JavaScript to update the screen every second, and this seems to be the cause.

However, I don't seem to have this problem with Chrome or Safari.

Is there a way to resolve this for Firefox?

[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/h6CsytPXn4qrTdQaj08d?p=preview).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.7" data-semver="1.0.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-init="updatetimer()">
    <div>seconds: {{counter}}</div>
    <select ng-model="something" ng-options="n.name for n in namelist">
      <option value="">select person</option>    
    </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

var ctrl = ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.counter=0;

    $scope.namelist = [
      {name: "Name1"}, {name: "Name2"}, {name: "Name3"}, {name: "Name4"}, {name: "Name5"},
      {name: "Name6"}, {name: "Name7"}, {name: "Name8"}, {name: "Name9"}, {name: "Name10"},
      {name: "Name11"}, {name: "Name12"}, {name: "Name13"}, {name: "Name14"},
      {name: "Name15"}, {name: "Name16"}, {name: "Name17"}, {name: "Name18"},
      {name: "Name19"}, {name: "Name20"}, {name: "Name21"}, {name: "Name22"},
      {name: "Name23"}, {name: "Name24"}, {name: "Name25"}, {name: "Name26"},
      {name: "Name27"}, {name: "Name28"}, {name: "Name29"}, {name: "Name30"}
   ];

  $scope.updatetimer = function() {

    var updater = function() {
      $scope.counter++;
      $timeout(updater, 1000);
    }
    updater();
  };

}];
```

Comment: Timer will fire the $digest loop every second, and cause re-evaluation of ng-options expression each time. I don't think you can do anything about it beside creating your own directive that would use jQuery to generate the un-binded drop-down on the first run and ignore the successive $digest loops.

Comment: @Stewie, what is it that triggers the $digest loops?  The `$scope` within that function? If so, maybe put the timer function in a directive, and have it update the dom the old fashioned way - angular.element(element).html(counter)...

Comment: I agree, that sounds like a better idea. In that case the OP would also have to set the third parameter (`invokeApply`) to false in $timeout function.

Comment: Does the screen absolutely have to be updated every second, or would something like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) be helpful?

Comment: +Stewie, can you make your first response the answer to the question. The real thing here seems to be the digest loop, and I'd like to be able to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Im using firefox 26.0, and I don't experience the problem.

Comment: I could not reproduce it either. Firefox 28 (Aurora)

Comment: Works fine on Firfox 25 on Mac. What is your firefox version and OS ?

Comment: A few of us (on Macs) are having this issue in Firefox 26.0, Aurora 21.0a2 and Aurora 28.0a2.

Comment: I can see the problem using FF 26.0 on Win7

Comment: Can you please say why you need to update with a timeout every 1 second? Looks like you're doing it wrong. Comment what you want to achieve with that, is the nameList updated too frequently? How?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the creating the 'option' elements through **ng-options** is the root cause to this issue.

I've altered the code a bit to make sure if that's the problem

See the plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/DLf2wvVGXRiwci6FhqQO?p=preview

What I've done is to move the creation logic of the options to **ng-repeat**.  That'll fix the issue for now.

Comment: Yes, but there's still that $timeout() in the code, which looks like it's the wrong approach of doing things. You may "fix" the problem, but looks like the OP may not be doing things properly (depends) and should provide more info or a more complete sample code to fix that. The cases where $timeout() is needed are rare, and outside of that, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Please update the angularjs to v1.2.15

http://plnkr.co/edit/pTnzpKAwFjugRVpuprFF?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Some people will still face this problem.

Here is the fix:

```
 if (existingOption.id !== option.id) {
    lastElement.val(existingOption.id = option.id);
 }
-if (existingOption.element.selected !== option.selected) {
+if (existingOption.selected !== option.selected) {
      lastElement.prop('selected', (existingOption.selected = option.selected));
 }
} else {
```

Add this patch directly into the angular core. This bug still persists in v1.2.8

Answer (score 0):

That's a AngularJS older version issue basically prior to 1.0.7, it's been fixed in 1.0.7 version, if you using anything older than 1.0.7 then you will be getting the same issue.