# Angular.js select looses focues option when $scope.$apply()

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a quite straightforward select element like that:

```
<select id="selectCurrency" selectmodel="currencyPair" class="select"
        ng-model="currencyPair" ng-options="ft.id as ft.name for ft in contentChart"
        ng-change="currencyPairChange(currencyPair)">
</select>
```

When I drop down the select, focus any option other then the first one and then the controller calls $scope.$apply(), focus is going back to the first option automatically.

I have no clue how to avoid such behaviour.
Any help strongly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and replicate the behaviour

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/u5n8w/1/

Comment: If you remove $scope.$apply() focus stays on what you select, but the problem is when $scope.$apply() is called. I need it in my use cases so you cannot remove it.

Comment: Even using [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5n8w/1/), I don't find anything wrong. It is staying where it should. Are you sure that the error is replicated in the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58475/discussion-between-damian-and-ma08).

Comment: That is how it behaves in Firefox 31: http://i.imgur.com/EboYlLu.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I got the idea [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498123/firefox-select-dropdown-keeps-refreshing-reverting-to-default-option-due-to-runn). Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5n8w/14/).

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
    {{rate}}
    <select id="selectRate" ng-model="rate" data-ng-click="suspendDigest()">
     <option ng-repeat="ft in rateChart" value="{{ft.id}}">{{ft.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function SelectCtrl($scope,$interval) {
 //$scope.rate='S';
 $scope.rateChart = [
   {id: 'S', name: 'buy rate'},
   {id: 'K', name: 'sell rate'},
   {id: 'R', name: 'average rate'}
];

setInterval(function(){        
   $scope.$apply();
}, 2000);
}
```